# how to check if the tag exists in the rest web service request

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, post

I have a restful webservice with below structure :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "test/abc", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
```

I have to check the payload values before extracting the values that whether certain key exists in the payload for this request. For example This is the request :

```
{"test1":"2",
"test2":"","additional":{"test3":"2"}}
```

I want to check if the "additional" tag exists in the request payload before extracting the values for the "additional" because otherwise it give NPE.

I have been using this but no success :

```
if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(params.additional().toString()))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you get `params`?

Comment: What is your method signature like? Do you use Jackson?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first have to check for `null` before accessing the `toString()`-Method. So do

```
if(params != null && params.additional() != null)
```

before your `if`-statement